# trying to get status bar inline with text

Tags: html, css

Im trying to code some status bars, however I can't seem to get the text and the correlating bar on the same line. I had some luck using the  attribute however when I did that the bar went to the far right, this is even after floating it left. I also tried a  as well but that didn't work.

```
<h5 class="card-header">Character info</h5>
       <div class="card-body">
          <p>Age:</p>
          <p>County:</p>
          <p>Job:</p>
          <p>Other Stats:</p>

    <div id="container_progressFood">
               <div class="progressFood" style="width: 25%;"> Food:
               <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" 
 role="progressbar"style="height: 20px; width: 75%; float: left" aria-  valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div> 
          </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want red bar on right of the text. I have used `float:right` instead of `left` on `.progress-bar` class element inline style and set width to 30:70. Although its working fine on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/5b2qwavs/1/) without width change.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h5 class="card-header">Character info</h5>
       <div class="card-body">
          <p>Age:</p>
          <p>County:</p>
          <p>Job:</p>
          <p>Other Stats:</p>

    <div id="container_progressFood">
               <div class="progressFood" style="width: 30%;float:left;"> Food:
               <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" 
 role="progressbar"style="height: 20px; width: 70%; float: right" aria-  valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div> 
          </div>
          </div>
```